# django celery not executing tasks.py in digitalocean server

Tags: python, django, celery, digital-ocean

I used `Celery` in my `django` project for schedule tasks, it was kinda perfect in local server, I upload this update to my `digitalocean` server, and after 3 days of searching and fixing issues I couldn't understand that pinch of mistakes I did !  , 
here is my project structure

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── corsa
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── other
```

tasks.py :

```
@shared_task
def just_testing():
    print('    test log     ')

@shared_task
def tasks_to_do_daily():
    # some stuff to do daily 

@shared_task
def tasks_to_do_weekly():
    # some stuff to do weekly
```

celery.py :

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'corsa.settings')

app = Celery('corsa')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()



app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-contrab1': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.just_testing',
        'schedule': 6.0,
    },
    'add-contrab2': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.tasks_to_do_daily',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='26', hour='09'),
    },

    'add-contrab3': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.tasks_to_do_weekly',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='00', hour='00', day_of_week='sat,tue'),
    },
}

app.conf.CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Hong_Kong'
```

settings.py :

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
```

Ok, now issues part ..

- For local

I tried these commends `celery -A corsa worker -l info` , `celery -A corsa beat -l info` , `celery worker -A corsa --loglevel=INFO` all of theme working with no errors, but not doing any tasks code of tasks.py at all !

the only one working fine with me is :

```
celery -A corsa worker -B
```

I don't know why, I searched for the reason but couldn't find a clear answer explain the reason

- For DigitalOcean

I follow up this tutorial for digitalocean server [part title : Managing The Worker Process in Production with Supervisord](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html) and [this Chinese website (translated by google)](https://www.cnblogs.com/wumingxiaoyao/p/8514398.html) but didn't work as should be with me, I changed the commend part from `celery worker -A corsa --loglevel=INFO` to `celery -A corsa worker -B` but still noting wokring at all ! 
BTW, all commends related with `Supervisord` are working perfectly as commends, but still tasks.py not executed at all !

```
    sudo supervisorctl reread
    sudo supervisorctl update
    sudo supervisorctl stop corsa
    sudo supervisorctl start corsa
    sudo supervisorctl status corsa
```

So for server part still I don't know what the issues and how to fix . any help please ?

Comment: `amqp://localhost` - first of all, do you have running instance of RabbitMQ on your local machine?

Comment: yes, in local machine everything perfect @Greenev

Comment: and what about remote? could your celery app connect to the broker? probably you also should add some logs to your question

Comment: yes it's connected, but not doing executing tasks

Comment: what you mean they are not executing? add some specifics. do you see tasks are appearing in the queue? does the worker consume from that queue?

Comment: I mean the tasks in app.tasks.py, no I didn't see it

Comment: check if you are able to get a task in queue by calling `taskname.apply_async((), {}, queue='testqueue')`, in this case you will know the problem is in celery-beat

Comment: How did you set up redis + celery in digitalocean
please look amy question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364039/how-to-connect-redis-for-celery-to-a-django-app-deployed-in-digital-ocean