# How to connect redis for celery to a django app deployed in digital ocean

Tags: django, redis, digital-ocean, django-celery

I hae recently deployed a django app in digitalocean. My app uses celery and redis for several email sending puposes and scheduled tasks. I have been searching for a documentation on how to connect redis and how to det the celery worker running for my app in digital ocean, but I am unable to find any proper way or documentation.

Please can someone tell me how to exactly setup this in digital ocean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The django app would use the celery client to connect to redis like `app = Celery('your App', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')` where the connection string points to your redis instance